# Google Analytics Reporting API: Possible to get pivot table of page and their views from each country?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I currently have a table like

`Page | Views | Singapore | US  | Country A | ...
-----|-------|-----------|-----|-----------| ...
A    | 200   | 50        | 100 | 30        | ...
B    | 220   | 20        | 150 | 20        | ...`

Generated from the following query:

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXXXX",
      "pageSize": "5",
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "startDate": "2017-10-01",
          "endDate": "2017-10-31"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:pageviews"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name": "ga:pageTitle"
        }
      ],
      "orderBys": [
        {
          "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
          "fieldName": "ga:pageviews"
        }
      ],
      "pivots": [
        {
          "dimensions": [
            {
              "name": "ga:country"
            }
          ],
          "metrics": [
            {
              "expression": "ga:pageviews"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want only focus only on specific countries. For example I only want to see Singapore and US columns without any other country data. How can I do that? Total views can still stay and include data from other countries.

If I provide a list of countries can it always show those columns even if theres no views?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but you try playing around with the [Request Composer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/) which allows you to build up a pivot table request using the Analytics Reporting API V4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few questions:

**How to filter on specific countries?**
You can use the query filters or segment to achieve this. The query explorer will help you build the correct filters:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/.

Note: the operator for `OR` is `,` ([see reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#OR)).

[image]

**"can it always show those columns even if theres no views?"**
By default no: Google Analytics only returns data it has. If it has no views, it has no data, thus won't return anything. The reason is that it would waste processing power and network bandwidth to return data that doesn't exist in GA. You will have to rebuild the missing data yourself.

You might want to try the [`includeEmptyRows`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.include_empty_rows) of the V4 reporting API though, which is set by default to `FALSE`, as this might do what you're looking for.

**Note on the country dimension**
Instead of using `ga:country`, you can use [`ga:countryIsoCode`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network&jump=ga_countryisocode) to filter on 2-letter country codes and not have to deal with percent encoding for countries which are composed of several words (e.g. `US` vs. `United%20States`).

Comment: Thanks Max, but can I check if I can have an Others column that include the views from any other location other than the list provided?

Comment: For countries you won't see `(others)`, because the cardinality is too low (around 250). You may see it for other dimensions depending on your data: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671?hl=en

Comment: You might want to try the `includeEmptyRows` of the V4 reporting API though, which is set by default to `FALSE`, as this might do what you're looking for (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.include_empty_rows)